# Render all from react component into .setHTML() Mapbox-gl-js with React

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, react

How can I Render react component inside .setHTML() whe in create popup?

```
import PopUpClick from "../../components/Map/PopUpClick";

map.on('click', 'mapPins', function(e) {
            map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
            const coordinates = e.features[0].geometry.coordinates.slice();
            const name = e.features[0].properties.title;
            const img = e.features[0].properties.img_url;
            const id = e.features[0].properties.pin_id;
            // const popUpHTML = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
            //     <PopUpClick
            //         name={name}
            //         img={img}
            //         id={id}
            //     />
            // );

            const popUpHTML = (<PopUpClick
                    name={name}
                    img={img}
                    id={id}
                />
            );

            new mapboxgl.Popup({
                closeButton: false,
                offset: 16,
                anchor: 'top'
            }).setLngLat(coordinates)
            .setHTML(popUpHTML)
            .addTo(map);
        });
```

When I click on symbol marker I got [object Object] in my div [image]

I need all functionality from react component, and with ReactDOMServer.renderToString i got only pure HTML.
I need to have all react stuff ass Redux and click listeners.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do with on click event instead of sethtml use setdomcontent and create button in that after that put you react component in onclick add event listener refrence link
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64182029/15570982

Answer (score 0):

You need to render the HTML content in an element first,

Add the following import to the map script:

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
```

And the code for adding a component should be something like this:

```
let popupNode = document.createElement('div');
const root = createRoot(popupNode);
root.render<PopUpClick
                name={name}
                img={img}
                id={id}
            />);

new mapboxgl.Popup({
            closeButton: false,
            offset: 16,
            anchor: 'top'
        })
      .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
      .setDOMContent(popupNode)
      .addTo(map.current);
```

That should work for you,
You can see an example of this (but using maplibre-gl, which should act the same, i just don't have a mapbox token) [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-wafd72?file=src%2FMapObject.jsx)